# Accessing a Super's Member of different type with the same variable name

Tags: java, subclass

Consider the following superclass and subclass pair, how do you access the superclass member?

```
class Super { 
    Number aNumber; 
} 

class Subbie extends Super { 
    Float aNumber; 
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to go through basics of `Inheritance`. You can start with this tutorial: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Come on - the question is not that bad... it is fair enough to point towards tutorials - but -3?

Comment: @dngfng: This is clearly a direct post of a homework question, with no effort whatsoever by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the super Member by `super.aNumber` provided it is an instance of the Subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the attribute does not have a visiblity modifier, it is assumed to be package private. `Subbie` will only be able to access `Super`'s `aNumber` if they're in the same package.

If it was, you could access it like this: `super.aNumber`. Notice `super` here is a keyword that implicitly refers to the superclass, and doesn't have anything to do with the superclass being named `Super`.

```
class Super { 
    Number aNumber; 
} 

class Subbie extends Super { 
    Float aNumber; 
    public Number getNumberFromSuper() { 
        return super.aNumber;
    }
}
```

I'd suggest to take a read on the excellent Java tutorials online, for instance:

- [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a field with different keywords known as *Access Modifiers* (check the links at the end for a detailed explanation on this topic), each one defining a scope for access/use. I'll focus this explanation on fields.

*Public:* Accessible by everyone. This Access Modifier is regulary used with methods and not with fields. In Java, it is encouraged the use of `get` and `set` methods to access the value of a field and change it (respectively). You can access a field this way:

```
AClass c = new AClass();
c.publicField = 3; //Setting a value in a field, int in this case
int sum = c.publicField + 4; //Obtaining the value of publicField to use it
```

*Private:* Definining a field as private makes it visible only to the class itself, meaning no one outside the boundaries of a class will be able to see that field. A common class in Java usually has private fields and accessors (`get` & `set` methods).

```
public class AClass {

    public int publicField;
    private String privateField = "Can't see me!";

    public String getPrivateField() {
        return privateField;
    }

    public void setPrivateField(String newValue) {
        privateField = newVaule;
    }

}
```

Getters and Setters let you control the access to your private fields, allowing you to perform any logic you desire before updating the value of that field or preparing a field in a particular before returning its value if you need it.

*Protected:* Only subclasses of a class and classes in the same package can access a field defined with this keyword. In your case `Subbie` has access to the `protected` fields of `Super` and any other class in the same package as `Super` has access to those fields as well.

*No Access Modifier:* This is your current case and the answer to your question relies strongly on the structure of your classes. If they are in the same package, then you can access `Super`'s field from `Subbie`. Otherwise, if `Subbie` is in another package, you won't be able to access that field. This field is referenced as *Package-Private*.

Some related articles you might want to check:

1. [Inheritance in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
2. [Controlling the Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)